# JMeter count samplers in thread , passed samplers, failed samplers

Tags: statistics, jmeter

I am trying to do functional testing with JMeter for a Web service. I am trying to build a tractability metrics using JMeter itself for which I need the count of the samplers in a thread, no of passed samplers, failed samplers in a thread.

Is there any way to collect no of the samplers, failed or passed samplers in a thread?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By adding [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener to your test, you will be able to get the number of passed and failed requests details. Below is the purpose of aggregate report.

> The aggregate report creates a table row for each differently named
>   request in your test. For each request, it totals the response
>   information and provides request count, min, max, average, error rate,
>   approximate throughput (request/second) and Kilobytes per second
>   throughput. Once the test is done, the throughput is the actual
>   through for the duration of the entire test.

Also, you can leverage [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree), [View Results in Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) and [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to debug your samplers.

To enable functional test mode in JMeter, click on the **Test Plan** and then check **Functional Test Mode** check box as shown below.

[image: Functional Test Mode in JMeter]